# SQLAlchemy: is it possible to operate Query without bounding to session?

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, python-3.4

I want to execute the same SQL query from different processes by SQLAlchemy.
As I understand I must create new Session in every process. So for each new session I must recreate query:

```
session.query(...).filter(...)
etc.
```

It seems logical to save fully formed query separately from session. And then only apply this query to each session:

```
new_session.query(old_saved_query)
```

Is it possible?
Or there is some other way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`with_session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_session):

```
query = session.query(...).filter(...)
query.with_session(new_session)
```

It is also possible to create a query without a bound session:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Query

query = Query(...).filter(...)
query.with_session(session)
```